# django rest framework for multiple image upload

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I am having difficult time with Django Rest Framework for multiple image upload.What i want is, there is a rental table where user will fill about rental information along with multiple images at once(images can be like kitchen,living room,bathroom etc) for that rent they want to register. one rent can have multiple images,so i have image field with manytomany relation.I could not able to send multiple images to server or api. Only one image used to get stored on the server but after changing my database design and going to the ManyToManyField option even a single image won't get stored.

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

**Models.py**

```
 class Gallery(models.Model):
        image = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='upload/')
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = _('Gallery')
            verbose_name_plural = _('Galleries')

class Rental(models.Model):  
        listingName =  models.CharField(_("Lisitng Name"), max_length=255, blank=False, null=True,
            help_text=_("Title of the rental space"))
        property = models.CharField(_("Property type"),max_length=10,null=True)
        room = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("No of Rooms"), blank=False, null=True,
            help_text=_("Number of bedrooms available"))
        price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False,null=True)
        city =  models.CharField(_("City"), max_length=255, blank=False, null=True)
        image = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class GallerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields=('pk','image') 


class RentalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = GallerySerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Rental
        fields = ('pk','listingName','property','city','room','price','image')

    def create(self,validated_data):
        listingName=validated_data.get('listingName',None)
        property=validated_data.get('property',None)
        city=validated_data.get('city',None)
        room=validated_data.get('room',None)
        price=validated_data.get('price',None)
        image=validated_data.pop('image')
        return Rental.objects.create(listingName=listingName,property=property,city=city,
            room=room,price=price,image=image)
```

**Views.py**

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
        parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, )

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
        print('up_file is',uploaded_file)
        with open('/media/upload/'+uploaded_file.name, 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
                print('chunk',chunk)
                destination.write(chunk)
                destination.close()
        return Response(uploaded_file.name, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

class RentalList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RentalSerializer
    queryset = Rental.objects.all()
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        rental = self.get_queryset()
        serializer_rental = RentalSerializer(rental,many=True)
        return Response(serializer_rental.data)

    @permission_classes((IsAdminUser, ))
    def post(self,request,format=None):
        user=request.user
        serializer_rental = RentalSerializer(data=request.data,context={'user':user})
        if serializer_rental.is_valid():
            serializer_rental.save()
            return Response(serializer_rental.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer_rental.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class RentalDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset=Rental.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RentalSerializer
```

**Frontend part for sending multiple image at once**

```
 onDrop(files) {
          console.log('Received files: ', files);
          this.setState({
              files: files
          });
           var image = new FormData(files);
           console.log('formdata image',image);
            var multiple_image = files;
            console.log('multiple_image',multiple_image);
            $.each(multiple_image,function(i,file){
              image.append('image_'+i,file);
            });
            console.log('images are',image);
           $.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost:8000/api/upload/',
            data:image,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            type:'POST',
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
           });
        }
```

Request payload on the console shows all the images.What might be the issue? What have i done wrong?

Comment: Could you please also post your `urls.py` file ? It would help a lot to try and reproduce this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have missed `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` in settings.py file. If you have missed or misconfigured it, django would place the file in some other location out of your project depending on your OS (for me django placed the file in `/home/username/`) . Check whether there is any such folder in your computer.

If you have configured `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` in settings.py please update them the question.

Comment: I updated my question with media_url and medi_root configuration.